# variable "totalMonedas" me devuelve "undefined"

Tags: javascript

Saludos poseo el siguiente código, la variable **totalMonedas** me retorna **undefined**:

```
function sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos(){
   var totalMonedas = 0; 
   for (var i=0 ; i<5 ; i++ ){
   totalMonedas = totalMonedas + 0.25;
    }
   console.log(totalMonedas);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos no te olvides de llamar a tu función:

```js
function sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos(){
   var totalMonedas = 0; 
   for (var i=0 ; i<5 ; i++ ){
   totalMonedas = totalMonedas + 0.25;
    }
   console.log(totalMonedas);
}
//llamando a la funcion
sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos();
```

la función en si funciona bien, quizá no esta bien planteado tu problema o estas llamando mal a dicha función.

Answer (score 1):

El código está bien, sí lo ejecutas en la consola generará esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta. En cuanto tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta. - Desde revisión